# Laravel PHP, navbar "not active"

Tags: php, css, laravel

My navbar in one of my laravel (php framework) project suddenly stopped working, I think I've tried everything with it but nothing works nor get me back to the point where it was working, any solutions or suggestions how to fix this issue?
navbar

```xml
<div class="container mx-auto flex justify-between p-4">
  <h1 class="text-xl font-black">stackoverflow</h1>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
    <a href="{{ route('about') }}" class="text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-black transition">About</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

web.php

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
})->name('about');
```

default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>sss</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}">
</head>
<body class='bg-sky-500 text-white'>
    <header class="fixed bg-sky-400 top-0 left-0 right-0" z-50>
        <div class="container mx-auto flex justify-between p-4">
            <h1 class="text-xl font-black">ssss</h1>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
                <a href="{{ route('about') }}" class="text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-black transition">About</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        @yield('page-content')
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="container mx-auto p4">
            <p>&copy; 
                <a>ssss</a>
                <a href="{{ url('ssss') }}"class="bg-color-pink-500 text-center py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-purple-500 transition">sss</a> 
                <a href="{{ url('ssss') }}"class="bg-color-pink-500 text-center py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-purple-500 transition">ssss</a>
                </p>
            

        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
https://github.com/wsamselbaudat/LaravelProject
resources/views/
2 blade.php files(ignore dashborad), on the about page the navbar is working perfectly fine, I want the navbar to be working on index.blade.php

Comment: Can you send us code from parent page? HTML and routes seem fine, maybe you forgot to include it?

Comment: I used: 
@yield('page-content') 
@extends('layouts.default')
for the entire project, the navbar is in layouts.default which I guess (I am not totally sure, I am a Laravel novice) should be my parent page, if it doesn't help I can send you the code for it, just lmk if it's the parent page.

Comment: share the code of your `parent/master/main/default` layout, seems to me that the parent layout is named `default` according to your comment. Important note: please add code to your question, not in comment

Comment: and what does it mean by nothing works? does not redirect to other page? route not working? current navbar is not active? your question is very confusing

Comment: ``<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('home') ? 'active' : '' }} text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>`` should work. When ever you're on the home route, home menu item will be selected, usually bold.

Comment: what exactly meas : "stopped working" ?

Comment: That is was working at some point of my project, now it suddenly stopped, I noticed that it works fine on the /about.blade.php, (github with all the files included in edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for current url using the request() helper is() method
or can get the current url using request()->url() method and compare it with the link route url

Try this

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="@if(request()->is('/')) your-active-class @endif text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="@if(request()->is('/about')) your-active-class @endif text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="@if(request()->url()==route('home')) your-active-class @endif text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
<a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="@if(request()->url()==route('about')) your-active-class @endif text-lg mx-2 text-white hover:text-pink-500 transition">Home</a>
```

Comment: or simply use the ``Route::currentRouteNamed('route-name')`` helper method  as ``{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('home') ? 'active-class' : '' }}``

Comment: None of this works for me, added the whole default page is that helps you

Comment: check for url matching by dumping current url and the route name url, if these are the same then above methods must work just fine